# How do you get formatted content of a post using the WordPress API?

Tags: customization

I tried using

```
<?php
$my_id = 7;
$post_id_7 = get_post($my_id); 
echo $post_id_7->post_content;
?>
```

based on the [documentation here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post).

The article I'm trying to retrieve has Short Code, which is picked up by a plugin on my site, and then formatted into HTML.

The problem is when I output the post_content to the site, the short code isn't picked up by the plugin, and I effectively just write out the short code straight to the browser.

Is there a way to get the short code evaluated properly?  Or am I using the wrong function?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Post's object field contains raw content as it is stored in database. This should format it to how it appears when retrieved with template tags:

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

This filters runs number of formatting functions, including shortcodes parsing. Something close to this:

```
>>>>>   the_content
8   (object) WP_Embed -> run_shortcode (1) 
    (object) WP_Embed -> autoembed (1) 
10  wptexturize (1) 
    convert_smilies (1) 
    convert_chars (1) 
    wpautop (1) 
    shortcode_unautop (1) 
    prepend_attachment (1) 
11  capital_P_dangit (1) 
    do_shortcode (1)
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. I have been looking on the codex for like an hour.

Comment: *@Joseph* - Though many in the core WordPress community are very proud of the Codex I too find it extremely difficult to use to find anything in it unless you already know what you are looking for. Thank goodness for WordPress Answers!

Comment: exactly what I was looking :)

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I tend to do a text search on a local copy of core when I'm in that situation... but the codex usually clues me into what text to do the search on ;-)